# Get all custom posts with a certain taxonomy

Tags: posts, wp-query

So the site i am working on has a Custom Post type of "Case Results" and one of the columns is "Type of Case". On a certain page I need to get all of these "Case Results with a "Type of Case" of "Criminal Defense Case". I can't seem to figure out which arguments will get me this in WP_Query.

I have tried many combinations but my most recent attempt looks like:

```
        $args = [
            'post_type' => 'case-results',
            'tax_query' => [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'type-of-case',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'term' => 'criminal-defense-case'
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper argument to your tax query is `terms`, not `term`. You can see this in one of the examples in the Codex:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'bob',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Assuming that your post types, and taxonomies are what they appear to be, and the slugs are correct, with that change your code should work.

Comment: I have changed 'term' to 'terms' and still don't seem to be getting the correct results. I am a career developer but am just starting to work with wordpress so it may very well be that I have some other thing off by one letter as well

Comment: Run your query (corrected) and post the SQL. To do that for the example above I'd do `var_dump($query->request);`

Comment: SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_msh_posts.ID FROM wp_msh_posts WHERE 1=1 AND 0 = 1 AND wp_msh_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'case-results', 'soliloquy', 'custom_type') AND (wp_msh_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_msh_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_msh_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_msh_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_msh_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 6